# how to create using build.xml a file whose name consists of the date and time of creation

Tags: xml, eclipse, ant, build.xml

how to create using build.xml a file whose name consists of the date and time of creation. Example: 25.03.19_15:40.jar

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with the [tstamp](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/tstamp.html) Ant task, for instance:

```
<target name="test.timestamp">
  <!-- create a timestamp with the specified format -->
  <tstamp>
    <format property="now" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm"/>
  </tstamp>
  <!-- create an empty jar file (except for the manifest) with the generated name --> 
  <jar destfile="${now}.jar" basedir="." excludes="**/*" filesonly="true"/>
</target>
```

Note that in the example the date format uses `-` rather than `:`, as colons in a file name are not valid on Windows OSes.

Answer (score 0):

```
<target name="-post-jar">
    
<tstamp>`enter code here`
  <format property="now" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm"/>
</tstamp>

<jar jarfile="C:/Users/nraj`enter code here`agopal/Desktop/Jar_Name_${now}.jar"
```

It working by using above method.